# ISA - intra year profits and switching process

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, mutual-funds, isa

I would like to open an ISA account to invest in funds and I see that the maximum allowance is increasing to 15,000 GBP in few months.

My understanding is that all incomes generated in the ISA are tax free. But does this also apply to potential gains that are realized within the tax year?

In other words, it is not clear if (in order to benefit from tax benefits) I need to hold my investments until the end of the tax year.

Just to make an example. Suppose that tomorrow I invest 10,000£ in a fund and this increase in value to 12,000 in 5 months time (in october, so before the end of the tax year). In october I decide to realize the profit, thus I sell the fund. My gain is 2,000£. Is it tax free?

If I then reinvest (still 10,000£) in another fund, and I realize another profit by selling it just 1 month later (november) is this other gain still tax free?

Just to summarize, it is not clear if realizing profits by switching between funds actually leads to tax free income or there is some condition to meet in order to qualify for tax free treatment (eg. gains from "trading" the fund by switching from equity to monetary funds are not allowed and thus they are taxed). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're overthinking it.

The ISA limit applies to the amount you invest into the ISA. In your example, £10,000. Whether that then fluctuates with performance is irrelevant. Even if you realise aprofit or a loss, nobody is watching it.

You merely count the amount you originally contributed into the ISA wrapper. When they add up to £15,000; that's the limit reached.

(And by the way, remember that only money going into the ISA is counted. It doesn't matter if you -let's say - put £15k in, then remove 10k. You've reached the limit. You don't again have the chance to put £10k 'back in'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. Sorrry but I don't have any experience with ISA and fund investing in general. So, just to clarify... let's say that I start with 10,000 invested in FundA. It's an equity fund and market went up. After some time I think market is going to drop so I decide to sell the fund and realize the profit, let's say 1,000. If I decide to switch to another fund, FundB that is a monetary fund (so less risky) can I put my 11,000 (the original 10,000 plus the 1,000 profit) in FundB? It's still within the ISA allowance but am I allowed to act this way?

Comment: All of your analysis of Fund A to B, etc is unnecessary. You put £10,000 in. That's the amount that is counted towards your limit. You are free to add another £5,000. It doesn't matter whether that original £10k has gone up or down in value - it was £10,000 at time of contribution.

Count the value of the contributions that you put into the ISA. The performance afterwards is free of taxes. But the value of the contributions as they go in are the only amounts you need to pay attention to when thinking of the limit.

As I said, you're merely over-thinking it.

Comment: So in my example I would be allowed to put the 11,000£ obtained from sellinf FundA and add other 4,000£ to invest in total 15,000£ into FundB? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Let's break this down into more simple terms. You put £10,000 in. Regardless of how the fund then performs, you are still able to put £5,000 more in. That's because only the original contribution is counted. The gains/losses once invested aren't counted towards the limit. Is that clearer?

Comment: Sorry Chris, what is not clear is how the switch is considered. Switching from A to B involves a sell of A and a buy of B. Does the sell of A imply that I moved out from my ISA so that when I want to come back into it to reinvest in B I am only allowed to put 5,000 (the difference between the allowance and the initial contribution)?

Comment: You're thinking one level too deep. Let me see if I can put your example into a real world scenario.

"John opens a Hargreaves Lansdown account, specifically their stock & shares ISA. He deposits £10,000. Using the £10,000 he invests in FundA and within 2 months, the value is up to £14,000. John then sells FundA. The £14,000 sits in his Hargreaves Lansdown account for a few weeks until John invests in FundB. After a month, FundB has fallen and the value of the investment is now £12,000." So - £10,000 went in to the ISA. That's the only figure that counts towards the limit. £5,000 still left.

Comment: Ok that clarifies my doubt. If money going out from the first investment still remains in the ISA then any new investment should be allowed within the ISA allowance. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: So important points. 1) The performance is irrelevant. 2) At any time you could add £5,000 as that is the leftover limit. 3) If the post-contribution performance did matter, you'd never know how much you could put in as you'd need real-world timing to calculate. 4) Any profits/losses are within the dealing account. The ISA limit is independent of performance. It counts only contributions into the ISA (here, just one transaction of £10,000). Selling and buying within the account is all happening INSIDE the ISA. It is seen as swapping from stocks to a 'temporary' cash balance.

Comment: Glad to help. I tried looking for a good explanation on Google, YouTube and the like. Nothing. Even MoneySavingExpert doesn't make this clear.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was opening an ISA account with Fidelity. What about the 5th of April deadline? Am I still on time to benefit from ISA allowance if I open the account now?

Comment: Yes, you have any time during the 2014/5 tax year to open an ISA.  Opening the account TODAY would give you an allocation of £11,880. Once the 1st of July arrives this will _automatically_ increase to £15,000. Fidelity will no doubt send correspondence to you to confirm this.

Comment: How does this all fit with the current allowance that exists outside ISAs? If I read correctly, we already have no taxation on profits up to 10,900£. That is actually a big amount for me. I shoul invest approximately 80,000£. The existing allowance means that if I get 10% profit (8,000£) this is already tax free. Only if I expect profits higher than 10,900£ it make sense to open an ISA and move 15,000£ into it. Is that correct?

Comment: I must say this though: wherever money is involved, if you don't understand it then DON'T do it. You are struggling with the logic of ISA limit calculation. That won't be anywhere near as complicated as picking funds (or heaven forbid, individual stocks) to go into the ISA. It is always worth seeking financial advice or even consulting Money Advice Service or Citizens Advice for more guidance. If you lost this £15,000 that you could potentially invest here, it's an expensive mistake when a few pounds to an adviser might have avoided such a mistake. Just my tuppence worth...

Comment: Your follow-up question is actually relating to Capital Gains Tax (CGT). If you hold something for a long time, then it may appreciate in value to the CGT limit. Seriously - my advice to you would be to seek help from a professional. Your questions are about basic foundations of investing. If you struggle now, then the chances of the investments going well are slim. #ToughLove

Comment: I will certainly ask some advice when selecting investments. I am surprised by this high allowance even otside an ISA. But probably I am wrong and this 10,900£ tax free allowance applies to all incomes (so salary+investments profits). It looks too high if it's just for investments profits.

Comment: Income Tax details: http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/rates/it.htm#1a

Capital Gains Tax details: http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/rates/cgt.htm#1

Comment: Thanks again Chris. I learnt a lot of stuff today and it's surprising how investing is made tax efficient for small investors (capital gain allowance + ISA). Since I'm stil in the valuation process, do you have any suggestion about which broker to use for investing? I have a Barclays bank account and a natural choice would be Barclays Stockbrokers. But I also saw Best Invest and Fidelity. The latter has a comparative table where it seems that it is the cheapest one. And the fund range is very similar. But I would appreciate your suggestion on this. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly... I'd spend more time doing research & making sure the rest of my finances were secure. Only invest money you can afford to lose. Make sure you have an emergency fund in place, are free of debts & then think of investing. Index trackers & diversified mutual funds may not be as exciting but they'd still be risky in the short-term. Stay away from single stocks or high-risk funds if you couldn't afford to lose all of your capital. Again, some sessions with an adviser will save you a great deal of losses in the future given how unsophisticated you are in the investment world currently.

Comment: By the way you put £ at the end of your numbers, I don't think you are a native English speaker. If you're originally from another country, this is a further reason why you need advice before risking £15,000 in investments. The financial world in the UK is very complex, the rules are plentiful. Seek advice. At the very least, paper-trade a few funds whilst you learn the ways of our system.

Comment: I actually have experience with investing but not with funds. And the English system, with tax allowances and ISAs, is new to me. Today you clarified most of the open issues I had. Now, as said, I'm trying to figure out which broker is best to invest. I already have a shortlist of absolute return funds and some balanced funds to invest into. I can tolerate high volatility so I'm confortable with risks associated with that kind of funds. Then, I would switch between investments when needed so it is important to have a broker that actually has no switching charges and with quick dealing times.

Comment: I can't help you any further, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

An ISA is a much simpler thing than I suspect you think it is.

It is a **wrapper** or **envelope**, and the point of it is that HMRC does not care *what happens inside the envelope*, or even about *extractions of funds from the envelope*; they only care about *insertions of funds into the envelope*. It is these insertions that are limited to £15k in a tax year; what happens to the funds once they're inside the envelope is your own business.

---

Some diagrams:

Initial investment of £10k. This is an *insertion into the envelope* and so counts against your £15k/tax year limit.

`+---------ISA-------+
----- £10k --------->              |
               +-------------------+`

So now you have this:

`+---------ISA-------+
               |  £10k of cash     |
               +-------------------+`

Buy fund:

`+---------ISA-------+
               |    £10k of ABC    |
               +-------------------+`

Fund appreciates. This happens inside the envelope; HMRC don't care:

`+---------ISA-------+
               |    £12k of ABC    |
               +-------------------+`

Sell fund. This happens inside the envelope; HMRC don't care:

`+---------ISA-------+
               |    £12k of cash   |
               +-------------------+`

Buy another fund. This happens inside the envelope; HMRC don't care:

`+---------ISA-----------------+
               | £10k of JKL & £2k of cash   |
               +-----------------------------+`

Fund appreciates. This happens inside the envelope; HMRC don't care:

`+---------ISA-----------------+
               | £11k of JKL & £2k of cash   |
               +-----------------------------+`

Sell fund. This happens inside the envelope; HMRC don't care:

`+---------ISA-------+
               |    £13k of cash   |
               +-------------------+`

Withdraw funds. This is an extraction from the envelope; HMRC don't care.

`+---------ISA-------+
<---- £13k ---------               |
               +-------------------+`

No capital gains liability, you don't even have to put this on your tax return (if applicable) - your £10k became £13k *inside an ISA envelope*, so HMRC don't care.

Note however that for the rest of that tax year, the most you can *insert* into an ISA would now be £5k:

`+---------ISA-------+
----- £5k --------->               |
               +-------------------+`

**even though the ISA is empty**. This is because the limit is to the *total inserted during the year*.

Comment: Hi, this is a very clear explanation and I thank you for that. I just suspect that I cannot meet all the requirements in order to qualify for a ISA account. Almost all the broker say that you must be UK resident. Well, I'm technically a French resident but I live and work (so I pay taxes) in UK. I obviously have a National Insurance Number (NIN). In the application form, it seems that the NIN is all you need. But does it matter that I am still a French resident even if I actually live and I am employed and pay taxes in UK?

Comment: I would suspect yes, based on [Can I have an ISA?](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/isa/faqs.htm#4) and [Residence](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/international/residence.htm) on HMRC's website, but I'd suggest giving them a call (they're actually pretty good on the phone, once you actually get through...)

Comment: Thanks for the useful links. As I am a full-time employee in UK, thus spending more than 183 days here, I should be considered as UK resident for tax purposes.